# How to keep qml Rectangle border from overlapping contents?

Tags: qml

I want a Rectangle to auto-size itself to fit exactly around its visual children.  If there is no border, then the following works great:

```
Rectangle {
    width:  childrenRect.width+(border.width*2)
    height: childrenRect.height+(border.width*2)
    ...
}
```

HOWEVER, if the Rectangle has a border, the children will overlap it.  I tried unsuccessfully wrapping the children in a container (`Column` in the example below) and using `anchor.margins` to shift the container over to miss the Rectangle's borders.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 600;  height: 600

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        border.width : 20
        border.color: "yellow"
        clip: true

        width: childrenRect.width+(border.width*2)
        height: childrenRect.height+(border.width*2)

        Column {
            anchors.margins: rect.border.width // does not work
            Text { height: 40; text: "FoooooooooooooooMumble" }
            Text { height: 40; text: "Bar" }
            Button { height: 40; text: "press me" }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Results from above code]

Can someone suggest how to do this?

Comment: Well, I figured it out.  A "margin" anchor is relative to the corresponding edge anchors,  and if an edge margin is undefined then the corresponding "margin" is ignored.  So if anchors.margins is set then anchors.left and anchors.top must also be set (or, I assume, right and bottom)

Answer (score 1):

For `anchors.margins` to work, the border anchors must be set (the margin space is relative to those).  For example:

```
Column {
            anchors.margins: rect.border.width
            anchors.left: rect.left
            anchors.top: rect.top
            ...
}
```